# Google apps account settings redirect to new host

Tags: g-suite, gmail, google

I have a employee whose Google apps account redirects:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/EditPasswd?hl=en

to another URL (their ISP's they use at home's website). I have tried this on multiple computers with the same results. Every time this one user's edit password link is redirected to their home ISP's login page (where they obviously cannot change their google password)

Is this a setting in Google apps? I checked the HOSTS file on their computer, (obviously not the problem if it happens across multiple computers), my DNS server settings (not it because it only happens to this one account, and the rest of my apps accounts for the rest of my employees are fine) and every setting in my google apps account that I can think of to no effect.

Comment: Sounds like they're catching NXDOMAIN and for some reason accounts.google.com isn't resolving properly on that ISP. They should contact the ISP's support.

Comment: This is from the office where the rest of the computers are resolving accounts.google.com correctly. Thats why I said its not a DNS or HOSTS file issue. Somehow its tied into the account. I just don't know how that is possible.